# json data for Ext4 store which requires a root element using SPRING MVC

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, extjs

i have an issue that i would like to solve. It is relative to get jsonData from an application which use Spring MVC. The reader would be a Ext4 store.

My service returns a json with this appearance:

```
[
    {
        "username":"john12",
        "password":"john12",
        "lastName":"john12",
    },
    {
        "username":"damian10",
        "password":"damian10",
        "lastName":"damian10",
    }
]
```

But i need something like this:

```
items: [
    {
        "username":"john12",
        "password":"john12",
        "lastName":"john12",
    },
    {
        "username":"damian10",
        "password":"damian10",
        "lastName":"damian10",
    }
]
```

My first question is if these characters [ ] are correct or it is neccesary to use only { }
for example:

```
items: {
    {
        "username":"john12",
        "password":"john12",
        "lastName":"john12",
    },
    {
        "username":"damian10",
        "password":"damian10",
        "lastName":"damian10",
    }
}
```

So i have to include the root to the list of users. Some code:

My Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/getUsers")
public @ResponseBody List<User> getUsersInJSON(){
    return userService.getUsers();
}
```

My conversion bean in aplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
        <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I read several post about roots and spring mvc with json but i haven't come to a conclusion. Could somebody explain me an easy solution for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the list in an object:

```
@ResponseBody Users
```

where

```
class Users {
   public List<User> items;
}
```

And yes, brackets [] are used for JSON arrays.

Comment: i saw a solution like this before. Is this solution a good practice?

Comment: Yeah, you are adapting the representation to match the client-side technology. Put the wrapper class next to your controller.

Comment: do you mean as a private class into the controller?

Comment: Nope, just a regular package-scoped class defined in the same .java file.